# Using OnPlatform to change the width of buttons for IOS and macOS

Tags: ios, macos, xaml, xamarin.forms

I can't work out why my image is not displaying as I want:

```
<Image
    Margin="0,0,0,10"
    HorizontalOptions="Center"
    Source="AppIcon"
    WidthRequest="{OnPlatform iOS=160,
                   macOS=80}" />
```

- iOS Simulator:

[image]

- macOS

[image]

I understand that there are issues with images on various devices and thus we add all of the images for the icon set in the assets - I have all those there.

My popup page is set to a width of 400. I thought that if I used the `OnPlatform' property it would be sufficient. My XAML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<pages:PopupPage
    x:Class="ElderlyInfirmRota.Pages.EditNamePopupPage"
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:animations="clr-namespace:Rg.Plugins.Popup.Animations;assembly=Rg.Plugins.Popup"
    xmlns:pages="clr-namespace:Rg.Plugins.Popup.Pages;assembly=Rg.Plugins.Popup">
    <!--  You can set an animation in the xaml file or in the csharp code behind  -->
    <pages:PopupPage.Animation>
        <animations:ScaleAnimation
            DurationIn="400"
            DurationOut="300"
            EasingIn="SinOut"
            EasingOut="SinIn"
            HasBackgroundAnimation="True"
            PositionIn="Center"
            PositionOut="Center"
            ScaleIn="1.2"
            ScaleOut="0.8" />
    </pages:PopupPage.Animation>

    <Frame
        Margin="50,0,50,0"
        BackgroundColor="{AppThemeBinding Dark=#2C2C2F,
                                          Light=White}"
        CornerRadius="10"
        HorizontalOptions="Center"
        VerticalOptions="Center"
        WidthRequest="400">
        <StackLayout
            Padding="10"
            HorizontalOptions="Center"
            VerticalOptions="Center">
            <Image
                Margin="0,0,0,10"
                HorizontalOptions="Center"
                Source="AppIcon"
                WidthRequest="{OnPlatform iOS=160,
                                          macOS=80}" />
            <Label
                x:Name="HeadingLabel"
                Margin="0,0,0,10"
                HorizontalOptions="Center"
                Text="Add / Edit Name" />
            <Label x:Name="NameLabel" Text="Name:" />
            <Entry
                x:Name="NameEntry"
                HorizontalOptions="Fill"
                Placeholder="Enter name" />
            <Grid HorizontalOptions="Fill">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Button
                    x:Name="OKButton"
                    Grid.Column="0"
                    Margin="20"
                    Padding="5"
                    BackgroundColor="#68686B"
                    BorderColor="WhiteSmoke"
                    BorderWidth="1"
                    Clicked="OKButton_Clicked"
                    HorizontalOptions="Fill"
                    Text="OK"
                    TextColor="White" />
                <Button
                    x:Name="CancelButton"
                    Grid.Column="1"
                    Margin="20"
                    Padding="5"
                    BackgroundColor="#68686B"
                    BorderColor="WhiteSmoke"
                    BorderWidth="1"
                    Clicked="CancelButton_Clicked"
                    HorizontalOptions="Fill"
                    Text="Cancel"
                    TextColor="White" />
            </Grid>
        </StackLayout>
    </Frame>

</pages:PopupPage>
```

Any guidance or pointers appreciated.

This is my assets json file:

```
{
  "images": [
    {
      "filename": "40.png",
      "size": "20x20",
      "scale": "2x",
      "idiom": "iphone"
    },
    {
      "filename": "60.png",
      "size": "20x20",
      "scale": "3x",
      "idiom": "iphone"
    },
    {
      "filename": "58.png",
      "size": "29x29",
      "scale": "2x",
      "idiom": "iphone"
    },
    {
      "filename": "87.png",
      "size": "29x29",
      "scale": "3x",
      "idiom": "iphone"
    },
    {
      "filename": "80.png",
      "size": "40x40",
      "scale": "2x",
      "idiom": "iphone"
    },
    {
      "filename": "120.png",
      "size": "40x40",
      "scale": "3x",
      "idiom": "iphone"
    },
    {
      "filename": "120-1.png",
      "size": "60x60",
      "scale": "2x",
      "idiom": "iphone"
    },
    {
      "filename": "180.png",
      "size": "60x60",
      "scale": "3x",
      "idiom": "iphone"
    },
    {
      "filename": "20.png",
      "size": "20x20",
      "scale": "1x",
      "idiom": "ipad"
    },
    {
      "filename": "40-1.png",
      "size": "20x20",
      "scale": "2x",
      "idiom": "ipad"
    },
    {
      "filename": "29.png",
      "size": "29x29",
      "scale": "1x",
      "idiom": "ipad"
    },
    {
      "filename": "58-1.png",
      "size": "29x29",
      "scale": "2x",
      "idiom": "ipad"
    },
    {
      "filename": "40-2.png",
      "size": "40x40",
      "scale": "1x",
      "idiom": "ipad"
    },
    {
      "filename": "80-1.png",
      "size": "40x40",
      "scale": "2x",
      "idiom": "ipad"
    },
    {
      "filename": "167.png",
      "size": "83.5x83.5",
      "scale": "2x",
      "idiom": "ipad"
    },
    {
      "filename": "76.png",
      "size": "76x76",
      "scale": "1x",
      "idiom": "ipad"
    },
    {
      "filename": "152.png",
      "size": "76x76",
      "scale": "2x",
      "idiom": "ipad"
    },
    {
      "filename": "1024.png",
      "size": "1024x1024",
      "scale": "1x",
      "idiom": "ios-marketing"
    },
    {
      "size": "60x60",
      "scale": "2x",
      "idiom": "car"
    },
    {
      "size": "60x60",
      "scale": "3x",
      "idiom": "car"
    },
    {
      "role": "notificationCenter",
      "size": "24x24",
      "subtype": "38mm",
      "scale": "2x",
      "idiom": "watch"
    },
    {
      "role": "notificationCenter",
      "size": "27.5x27.5",
      "subtype": "42mm",
      "scale": "2x",
      "idiom": "watch"
    },
    {
      "role": "companionSettings",
      "size": "29x29",
      "scale": "2x",
      "idiom": "watch"
    },
    {
      "role": "companionSettings",
      "size": "29x29",
      "scale": "3x",
      "idiom": "watch"
    },
    {
      "role": "appLauncher",
      "size": "40x40",
      "subtype": "38mm",
      "scale": "2x",
      "idiom": "watch"
    },
    {
      "role": "appLauncher",
      "size": "44x44",
      "subtype": "40mm",
      "scale": "2x",
      "idiom": "watch"
    },
    {
      "role": "appLauncher",
      "size": "50x50",
      "subtype": "44mm",
      "scale": "2x",
      "idiom": "watch"
    },
    {
      "role": "quickLook",
      "size": "86x86",
      "subtype": "38mm",
      "scale": "2x",
      "idiom": "watch"
    },
    {
      "role": "quickLook",
      "size": "98x98",
      "subtype": "42mm",
      "scale": "2x",
      "idiom": "watch"
    },
    {
      "role": "quickLook",
      "size": "108x108",
      "subtype": "44mm",
      "scale": "2x",
      "idiom": "watch"
    },
    {
      "size": "1024x1024",
      "scale": "1x",
      "idiom": "watch-marketing"
    },
    {
      "size": "16x16",
      "scale": "1x",
      "idiom": "mac"
    },
    {
      "size": "16x16",
      "scale": "2x",
      "idiom": "mac"
    },
    {
      "size": "32x32",
      "scale": "1x",
      "idiom": "mac"
    },
    {
      "size": "32x32",
      "scale": "2x",
      "idiom": "mac"
    },
    {
      "size": "128x128",
      "scale": "1x",
      "idiom": "mac"
    },
    {
      "size": "128x128",
      "scale": "2x",
      "idiom": "mac"
    },
    {
      "size": "256x256",
      "scale": "1x",
      "idiom": "mac"
    },
    {
      "size": "256x256",
      "scale": "2x",
      "idiom": "mac"
    },
    {
      "size": "512x512",
      "scale": "1x",
      "idiom": "mac"
    },
    {
      "size": "512x512",
      "scale": "2x",
      "idiom": "mac"
    }
  ],
  "info": {
    "version": 1,
    "author": "xcode"
  }
}
```

The file names don't adhere to the `xxxx@2x.png` approach but that should not matter because the json states the relationship.

---

## Update

I added a PNG as a resource (sized 1024 pixels) and tried this XAML:

```
<Image
    Margin="0,0,0,10"
    HorizontalOptions="Center"
    Source="AppIcon"
    WidthRequest="{OnPlatform iOS='160',
                              macOS='80'}" />

<Image Source="1024.png" WidthRequest="160" />
<Image Source="1024.png">
    <Image.WidthRequest>
        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:Double">
            <On Platform="iOS" Value="160" />
            <On Platform="macOS" Value="40" />
        </OnPlatform>
    </Image.WidthRequest>
</Image>
<Image Source="AppIcon">
    <Image.WidthRequest>
        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:Double">
            <On Platform="iOS" Value="160" />
            <On Platform="macOS" Value="40" />
        </OnPlatform>
    </Image.WidthRequest>
</Image>
```

The result:

[image]

It does not like using the AppIcon Resource on my simulator. Only from Resources folder.

Comment: Are you providing iOS project with different size of that image?

Comment: @Cfun Yes, both  have a full range of images at various sizes.

Comment: @Cfun I saw this: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/81578/xaml-not-working-for-image-widthrequest-heightrequest

Comment: @Cfun How about having a try with using `Resources` instead of `assets` to check that?

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT not familiar with iOS native project structure, if it is the same like Android and make a mistake by placing mdpi image in hdpi folder maybe could happen. Hope the emulator is not the issue.

Comment: @Cfun Hi, iOS also has the similar setting with Android(hdpi folder), but here Truckle has done that. Then suggest use [a past ways](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/images?tabs=windows#local-images) to check whehter it will work. If it works, I think this may be an issue.

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT My Resources folder is empty at the moment. Let me look.

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT The only way to use image sets via the VS-for-Mac IDE seems to be through the Assets folder.

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT I will try OnIdiom.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle Okey, but the `Resources` folder also can use in VS for Mac, it works in my local site.

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT But the docs say using resource folder is deprecated since iOS 9??

Comment: @AndrewTruckle Yeah, although it's a past way, but it always work until now. Just have a try to check whether it works, then we can know whehter it's an issue or a feature of `Assests` to occur that phenomenon.

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT which of my sized images should I put in the resource folder? And I assume I must name them correctly?

Comment: @AndrewTruckle You could select one size of image to check first. Not caring about name of it, because it always has a special name such as 'xxx.png'/`xxx@2x.png`.

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT See updated question.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle Thanks for updating. Therefore, the `Assests` problem in iOS should be the basic size of `Image` is too small. Do you have a check with the size of iOS Image whether is 1024*1024?

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT As mentioned, my app icon has all of the sizes up to 1024. I am going to try and add an image asset with three images and try with that instead of using the app icon. But it seems daft. And you can see my json file has the 1024 image there.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle Hi, the `1024.png` is `"scale": "1x"`, you need to add other scales for it. Almost iPhone Devices are using `2x` or `3x` scale now.

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT I have not checked yet. But do you notice something fundamental? The AppIcon adds the corner radius etc. The Image version via resources shows it as just the rectangle with a white background. This is why I wante dto use the AppIcon instead.

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT At the moment I have decided to display the popups on iOS using DisplayPromotAsync and my custom popup on macOS.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle Yeah, I didn't notice that. But I'm not suggesting you use Resources to show image. My meaning is that maybe you are using the same scale of image in `Assests`, that will make the effects be different. If you have found the solution, remember to update it in answer.

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT It’s a workaround because DisplayPromptAync does not offer icons. I just wondered if the Image command is locating the right file by using the image file name, so the 2x etc. But if it looked at the json it could find it. Can’t you just make a test and drag your icon in? See if it works? Then we know issue is my file names of the images in the icon set.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle Hi , I have tested in my local site, it shows as expected. Maybe the result will be affected by source type. I am using a png Image(320*320), not a icon source, you could check that.

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT What do you mean by icon source? The AppIcon resource is images. They are PNG. You can see that. I will leave this. Thanks for trying.

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT See my answer. 

Comment: @AndrewTruckle Okey, glad you have solved it. About your used `1024.png`, you also need to notice that the basic size of Image should match the used scene( `WidthRequest="{OnPlatform iOS='160',macOS='80'}"`), this should be realted with UI designs. Maybe you will need a UI designer to design the basic size of Image where need to use.

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT I am not in a position to have a dedicated designer for the UI. This is a hobby of mine. So the 160 should by should be 160, 320 etc? I plucked those figures out the air 160 / 80.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle Yes, the 160 better should be `160*160`(`160.png`),`320*320`(`160@2x.png`),`480*480`(`160@3x.png`).

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT That is good to know. Thanks. Out of interest, do you kow the official sizes being used on the standard popup windows that display on the macOS?

Comment: @AndrewTruckle There are no [official sizes](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/macos/icons-and-images/image-size-and-resolution/) for popup windows, that depends on the effect of UI your needs. I believe that will require some knowledge of aesthetic design. However, as a developer, we don't even know those :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have a workaround as mentioned to me in the comments.

I visited appicon.co website and created 3 versions of my 1024 PNG file:

[image]

I also ensured they were named correctly.

The I created an Image Set in the Assets (for both iOS and macOS):

[image]

Finally, I adjusted my XAML to use this image set:

```
<Image
    Margin="0,0,0,10"
    HorizontalOptions="Center"
    Source="AppLogo"
    WidthRequest="{OnPlatform iOS='160',
                              macOS='80'}" />
```

I don't know how to validate if the `OnPlatform` is coming up with the right sizes (I think they are now right). On the iOS simulator it now looks good:

[image]

So it would appear that it is not a good idea to use the **AppIcon** resource but a dedicated **Image Set** resource.

---

The only annoying thing is that building now gives warnings when I only add just the 3 images:

[image]

But I see that [issue](https://developercommunity2.visualstudio.com/t/Adding-new-image-set-to-iOS-app-produces/1050097) was raised last year with no official resolution.